# Some sites won't open in Firefox Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

Some sites won't open in Firefox. I'm using Tor with Firefox which I tunnel through system network in Ubuntu. After trying to install XAMPP and WordPress locally, it is not working like it always was. I check this [check.torproject.org](http://check.torproject.org) but it says I'm connected.

Comment: Have you tried using the official [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) to see if that works?

Comment: Also, giving an idea of what sites aren't working may help us answer your question. Are these Hidden Services (Onion Sites), or are they accessible outside of Tor normally?

Comment: Tor blocks requests to anything on the local network, so that would be why your local WordPress isn't loading.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about `torify` command. If so, Try to install ***FoxyProxy*** Extension for Firefox.

I used this command a couple of times and my Firefox got weird. After a lot of searching, still I don't know why this happens but foxyproxy is working for me.